# Adding matrix as pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, matrix

I have a function for what I pass a matrix and a variable as a pointer (I simplified it, maybe in this form it doesn't make sense, but I didn't want to paste the whole code :)

```
uint64_t returndata = 0;
uint32_t binary_lock = 0;

void initLamp(uint8_t time, const uint8_t *datatable, uint64_t *outdata)
{
    for(uint8_t k = 0; k < ROW; k++)
    {
        if(*(datatable + k * COLS) == time)
        {
            binary_lock |= (1 << k);
        }
    }
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        *outdata |= (1 << (3 * i));
    }
}
```

I have another file, called datafield.h, what consists the matrix:

```
static const uint8_t signal_table[][COLS] =
{        
    {22, 24, 63, 67}, // 1A
    {87, 89, 31, 35}, // 1B
    {0 ,  2, 21, 24}, // 1C
    {0 ,  3, 22, 43}, // 1D
}
```

In the main I need to refer to the function like this, to avoid errors and warnings:

```
int main(void)
{
    initLamp(0, *signal_table, &returndata);
}
```

The question is: I'm a bit sceptic using the main function. I'm almost sure that the usage of '&returndata' is correct, but why do I have to put the '*' operator before the 'signal_table'. I thought I would only need to give the address of the matrix like &signal_table, but with this it is not working.

Comment: `signal_table` is of type `const uint8_t [4][4]`. As an operand of unary `*`, `signal_table` is converted from `const uint8_t [4][4]` to `const uint8_t  (*)[4]` (pointer to array length 4 of `const uint8_t`), so `*signal_table` is of type `const uint8_t [4]`. As a function call argument, `*signal_table` is converted from `const uint8_t [4]` to `const uint8_t *`, which is compatible with the function parameter. It would be more natural to replace `*signal_table` with `&signal_table[0][0]`, which is also of type `const uint8_t *` and points to the same thing.

Comment: In general, using pointer arithmetic on a pointer to some element to access an element in a different row of a 2-D array (treating a 2-D array as a flat 1-D array) leads to undefined behavior. There is an exception for pointer to character types (`char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`) which can legitimately be used to access any byte of the 2-D array. It is possible that `uint8_t` is not defined as a character type on some C implementation (it could be defined as an extended integer type), which would disallow this usage. If `uint8_t` is the same type as `unsigned char` then it is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid writing needlessly obscure or complicated code when you could keep it simple. Your function should probably be written as:

```
void initLamp(uint8_t time, const uint8_t datatable[ROWS][COLS], uint64_t *outdata)
```

Or alternatively with VLA syntax:

```
void initLamp(uint8_t time, 
              size_t rows, 
              size_t cols, 
              const uint8_t datatable[rows][cols], 
              uint64_t *outdata)
```

In case of the latter, call it as:

```
initLamp(0, ROWS, COLS, signal_table, &returndata);
```

And the `for` loops should be simplified to use array syntax:

```
for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
  for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
  {
    datatable[r][c] = something;
  }
}
```

---

Another issue is the `1 << ...` parts of your code, which are likely hidden bugs. `1` is an integer constant of type `int`. You might end up shifting data into the sign bit which is an undefined behavior bug. In case of `uint64_t` you should rather be using `1ULL` or `(uint64_t)1`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, especially for the hidden bug, since I was struggling with it for some minutes.